# Index of a sublattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, integer-lattices

Assume that $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ is an integer lattice of rank $2$ and define for each integer $k$, $$\Lambda(k):=\Big\{(x_1,x_2) \in \Lambda: k\mid (x_1,x_2)\Big\}.$$ What is the index of $[\Lambda:\Lambda(k)] ?$

Comment: The index should be $k^2$, shouldn't it?  For instance, consider the square lattice $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}[i] \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.  Then for $\Lambda(2)$, we have $\mathbb{Z}[i]/2\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which has order $4$.

Comment: The lattice in your example is not contained in the integers I am afraid

Comment: Oh, come on, they're isomorphic; $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ as abelian groups.  So take $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\Lambda(2)$ and what I said is still true.  In general, you should try to show that the cosets of $\Lambda(k)$ in $\Lambda$ are represented by elements $(i,j)$ for $i,j \in \{0, 1, \ldots, k-1\}$.